# When I render my animation my main light source is not rendered. How can I get the light to show up in the final render?

Tags: rendering, light, lighting

[image]//i.stack.imgur.com/5XYUs.png
[image]

All help is appretiated

Comment: The bottom picture is preview render and the top is the final render

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up)

Answer (score 0):

Your light is in a different layer. Bring your light to layer number one. First, find where is light located in layers then select the light and press m to move to layer number one.